# infinite Slider in Svelte

Tags: javascript, arrays, slider, svelte, infinite-scroll

Trying to make a Dynamic `Slider` component with *infinite* data in both the `prev` and `next` buttons. However, I can't get the right Method to get it done.

Here You can find the code I wrote.

I took the approach of adding to the array in the last in the next button but I had problems with the `prev` button where the `slidesToShow` variable will have a negative value and the slider won't move.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let slider;
    export let slidesToShow = 4;
    export let array = [];
    let clonedArr = [...array];
    array = [...clonedArr, ...clonedArr, ...clonedArr, ...array];
    let gap = 0;
    let slidesToScroll = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    let childWidth;
    let sliderWidth;
    onMount(() => {
        initSlider();
    });
    console.log(array.length);
    const initSlider = () => {
        const style = getComputedStyle(slider);
        gap = parseInt(style.gap);
        sliderWidth = slider.clientWidth;
        childWidth = sliderWidth / slidesToShow - (gap - slidesToShow - 1);
    };

    const nextItem = () => {
        slidesToScroll++;
        if (slidesToScroll === array.length - slidesToShow) {
            const newArr = [...array];
            array = [...array, ...newArr];
        }
        console.log('slidercomponent next', slidesToScroll, array.length);
    };
    const prevItem = () => {
        slidesToScroll--;
        if (slidesToScroll === Math.floor(array.length / 2) - slidesToShow) {
            // slidesToScroll = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
            const newArr = [...array];
            array = [...newArr, ...array];
        }
        console.log(
            'slidercomponent prev',
            slidesToScroll,
            array.length,
            array.length / 2 - slidesToShow
        );
    };
</script>

<svelte:window on:resize={initSlider} />

<div class="grid grid-cols-slider gap-4 place-items-center w-full h-full ">
    <button on:click={prevItem} class="">
        <img src="static/images/icons-png/left-arrow.png" class="w-full h-full" alt="" />
    </button>
    <div id="slider">
        <div
            style="transform:translateX(-{(childWidth + gap) * slidesToShow}px)"
            id="slider-container"
            bind:this={slider}
        >
            {#each array as item, index}
                <div class="child" style="--width:{childWidth}px">
                    <img
                        src="static/images/icons-png/casio06.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="w-full h-full object-cover"
                    />
                    <div class="bg-red-500">item {item}</div>
                </div>
            {/each}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button on:click={nextItem} class="">
        <img src="static/images/icons-png/right-arrow.png" class="w-full h-full" alt="" />
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can write CSS variables [directly as component props](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives---style-props), by the way.

Comment: I didn't get the idea! I have already done that?

Comment: You are setting them via `style`, which is not necessary. I.e. `style="--width:{childWidth}px"` becomes `--width="{childWidth}px"`